# can't upload png image with transparent background with this code works good for jpg image

Tags: php, html, image

can't upload png image with transparent background with this code works good for jpg image any opinions

```
                <?php
   $hid =$_POST['id'];

   if(is_array($_FILES)) {
          if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
          $sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
          $targetPath = "images/hotels/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];
          $image_info = getimagesize($targetPath); 

          if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
    $orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetPath);
  $image_info = getimagesize($targetPath); 
  $width_orig  = $image_info[0]; // current width as found in image file
     $height_orig = $image_info[1]; // current height as found in image file
  $width = 1024; // new image width
     $height = 768; // new image height
   $destination_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($destination_image, $orig_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height,          $width_orig, $height_orig);
// This will just copy the new image over the original at the same filePath.
         imagejpeg($destination_image, $targetPath, 100);
       $full = "http://somewebsite.co.in/".$targetPath;
       ?> 

    <?php
   }
     else
    {
         echo "upload Failed";
      }
    }
     }
       ?>
```

Comment: JPEG only supports 24 bit, not 32 (alpha channel) . Use `imagepng()`

Answer (score 0):

As PedroLobito mentioned, your code is written only to support JPG. You use at least 2 functions dedicated only to JPG format: [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) and [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php). For PNG use [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) and [`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) instead.